# Proper way to register a Hibernate SessionEventListener with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I would like to implement and add a `SessionEventListener` to all Hibernate sessions in my spring-boot application. I know that one of the ways of doing that would be by calling `Session.addEventListeners()`.

I do not know how to be able to do that in a Spring boot application with JPA.

What is the proper way of achieving that, considering that my implementation of session listener needs to be a bean of the spring context? (so that some approach where I would specify just a class name would not be optimal).

Answer (score 2):

Well, analyzing better it became clear that the idea is that a `SessionEventListener` should be stateful, meaning that a new instance is created for each Session. Therefore it is not the case to try to use a single instance bean as the `SessionEventListener`.

So it seems the only approach is to use the hibernate property "`hibernate.session.events.auto`" with the fully qualified class name. And, in order to have access to the Spring context, use some way like accessing through some static method.